# ASP.NET MVC Simple case with JavaScript and Razor

Tags: asp.net-mvc

I have a very simple problem - I try to assign a server variable into a javascript variable;

e.g.

```
 var data = @(DateTime.Now.Day.ToString() + " " + System.Globalization.CultureInfo.GetCultureInfo("pl-PL").DateTimeFormat.GetMonthName(DateTime.Now.Month) + ", " + DateTime.Now.Year.ToString());

 alert(data);
```

the `alert` doesn't show, where's the bug ?

The source output is

```
var data = 4 , ;

alert(data);
```

but should be `4 december 2011`

Comment: did you view source the output? what do you see when you do?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to wrap it in quotes

```
var data = "@(DateTime.Now.Day.ToString() + " " + System.Globalization.CultureInfo.GetCultureInfo("pl-PL").DateTimeFormat.GetMonthName(DateTime.Now.Month) + ", " + DateTime.Now.Year.ToString())";
alert(data);
```

Then I get the following alert:

"5 grudzień, 2011"

If you think about it - without quotes wrapped around the string, it is not valid javascript.